# Problems with ggplot2 and geom_errorbar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Greeting, 
I'm having a hard time with ggplot2 and the geom_error function. 
I have a data frame with individuals(rows) and size(column 1) and density(column2). My aim is to plot influence of density on size in a quadratic model.
lm(size ~ poly(density, 2, raw=TRUE))
for that matter I used.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = density, y = size, col = Sexo)) + 
geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1)+                      
geom_point())
```

[image]

It went fine. But now I want to plot the same data set with `geom_errorbar`. I tried.

```
ggplot(cg.cvic, aes(x = as.factor(density), y = size, col = sex)) + 
    geom_errorbar(ymin = size-sd, ymax = size + sd))
```

And I'm guettint the response:

> Error in size - sd : non-numeric argument to binary operator

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From your description of your data, you don't have a column name `sd`. Without that, when you tell `ggplot2` `size - sd`, the only `sd` it can find is the standard deviation function `sd()`. And since subtraction isn't defined for functions, you get the error about giving a non-numeric (the function `sd`) to a binary operator (subtraction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly there is no column `sd` in your data frame. Moreover R has build in function `sd` which is a function not a variable or a number. So from R perspective you are trying to add variable to a function, so R tells you that one of the argument is non-numeric and your are trying to perform on him action which can only be perfomed on numbers. You have extract somehow the standard deviation of your model predictions, write it in your data frame and after that use it in ggplot. And don't name it `sd`, use something else.